# Model list becomes null when passing the view model to another method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am using ASP.NET MVC5

my ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel contains these:

```
 public List<Education> edus { get; set; }
 public List<Experience> workplaces { get; set; }
```

in my AccountController I declare the lists like so:

```
public List<Education> edus;
public List<Experience> workplaces;
```

I then populate them in ExternalLoginCallBack with no problem (debugged and they are as intended)

At the bottom I am trying to create the model and pass it to the "ExternalLoginConfirmation" like so:

```
 return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
                    {
                        Email = loginInfo.Email,
                        FirstName = ExternalLoginLinkedIn.FirstName,
                        LastName = ExternalLoginLinkedIn.LastName,
                        Country = ExternalLoginLinkedIn.Country,
                        Summary = ExternalLoginLinkedIn.Summary,
                        LinkedinPictureUrl = ExternalLoginLinkedIn.LinkedinPictureUrl,
                        Gender = ExternalLoginLinkedIn.Gender,
                        Birthday = ExternalLoginLinkedIn.Birthday,
                        edus = edus,
                        workplaces = workplaces

                    });
```

So far so good, putting a breakpoint here shows the model to be populated as intended, educations and workplaces have the correct lists.

Now when its time for the next method:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
```

the ExternalLoginConfirmationModel contains all the data, except for the two lists (edus and workplaces), which they are null then I get an error. 
What am I missing? Is it the garbage collector?

Comment: Have you checked the state of the lists in your AccountController? You are using the same reference in your AccountController  and in your ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel. If you set one of the references to null the other will be null as well.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow? where do I set the references to null and how do I check the state of the lists?

Comment: In your third code snippet you initialize your ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel edus and workplaces with the lists from your AccountController, do you? 
Maybe you set these lists in your AccountController to null somewhere in your logic. If that's so that will be the reason why your lists in the ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel will be null as well.

When you stop at the breakpoint to check the lists of you ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel check the lists of your AccountController as well (if possible). Do they still have the correct items or are they null as well?

Comment: Both methods are in AccountController and I do not set them to null anywhere. I just initialize them, add things to them, then suddenly they go null.

Comment: @crystyxn Is the method triggered ExternalLoginConfirmation? when return view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call `ExternalLoginConfirmation` from HTML page,
your model will bind only fields that you have in form.

That the reason all other fields pass and the lists become null.

You have two ways to solve this problem:

1. Save `edus` and `workplace` in a store in server side, and take them back in `ExternalLoginConfirmation` method.
2. Use [@HiddenFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor(v=vs.118).aspx) in you view to insert the lists as part of your form, so you will get them in `ExternalLoginConfirmation` method.

   **Edit**

You have another way to keep and fetch data.
Use session object.

`Session["edus"] = edus`

And you take it back in next controller with a cast.

`var edus = (List<Education>)Session["edus"]`

Comment: added `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.edus, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.workplaces, new { @class = "form-control" })` but now in the model edus and workplaces are not null but 0 ? did I do it incorrectly?

Comment: Did a loop like this `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.edus.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.edus[i], new { @class = "form-control" })
            }
            
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.workplaces.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.workplaces[i], new { @class = "form-control" })
            }`, now its count = 1, but null ...?

Comment: Looks like it worked, now to figure out why it says `Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.` and why I cannot seem to get EntityValidationErrors to display properly in the watch...